# How do i quit and print the events in one loop here

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

x = height,width = (800,600)

Display = pygame.display.set_mode(x)


pygame.display.set_caption("Blocky")

red = (157, 139, 215)
black = (0,0,0)

Display.fill(red)

pygame.draw.rect(Display,black,(120,450,600,50))

#It updates every frame

pygame.display.update()

excape = False

while not excape:
    for dork in pygame.event.get():  
      print(dork)
    if pygame.event == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
```

[image: Here's the result]

Here the print(dork) is working but when i click the exit button of the window it doesn't quit at all..
So how do i both print events and quit the application in 1 while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cycle through EVERY pygame event and check if the event is a quit.

```
while not excape:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            excape = True
```

Comment: I suggest to move the `pygame.quit()` call to the end of the program, otherwise you'll get ugly `pygame.error: display Surface quit` or `pygame.error: video system not initialized` errors if you blit something or flip the display in the while loop. You actually don't even need `pygame.quit()` it's only helpful for IDLE users (can't close the window without it).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should update the screen in the while not excape loop. 
Secondly, set the excape to `True` if pygame.event is equal to `pygame.QUIT`.
So your code will look like this:

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

x = height,width = (800,600)

Display = pygame.display.set_mode(x)


pygame.display.set_caption("Blocky")

red = (157, 139, 215)
black = (0,0,0)

Display.fill(red)

pygame.draw.rect(Display,black,(120,450,600,50))

#It updates every frame


excape = False

while not excape:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
      print(event)
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          excape = True
          pygame.quit()
          sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Take a look at my comment on the other answer. You can remove `pygame.quit()` unless you use the IDLE IDE and `quit()` should actually only be used in the REPL. You also need to change the `if pygame.event == pygame.QUIT:` line to `if dork.type == pygame.QUIT:` or better rename `dork` to `event`.